# How do I force Windows Server 2008 WAIK/SYSPREP to ask for the computer name?

Tags: windows-server-2008, deployment, sysprep, waik

I'm trying to generate an answer using the Windows Automated Installation Kit that will allow me to `SYSPREP` a machine image to:

1. Automatically set the Product Key
2. Automatically set the Timezone
3. Automatically set the Registered Organisation and Registered Owner
4. Generate fresh SID's
5. Ask for the computer name on first boot

I've made some headway with this, but when I try to set the Product Key, TimeZone and Registered Owner/Organisation using the `x86_Microsoft-Windows-Shell-Setup_neutral` component in the Specialize phase, when the machine boots after sysprep it skips asking for the computer name.

How do I achieve the above?

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid that there is no current built in functionality to allow this customization in a sysprepped image. It has to do with the fact that windows does not actually use the image to 'install' the software, the image is an all ready installed version of the software with certain presets. When you are running the install program all it really is doing is placing this pre-installed image onto the computer in question.

Microsoft's official response to this question is 'You can't do it with the 2008 sysprep functionality.'

If you want to customize your deployment options, Microsoft recommends the Microsoft Deployment Toolkit 2010. Which can be found [here.](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/solutionaccelerators/dd407791.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Using Windows 7 Sysprep apparently if you remove the asterisk from the ComputerName= entry, you will be prompted for a machine name on first boot.  Here is a long-winded description that I came across.  I don't know if it is applicable to 2008.

http://capitalhead.com/articles/force-sysprep-to-prompt-for-a-computer-name-during-mini-setup-in-windows-xp.aspx